# Deploy WAR in JBoss by passing parameters

Tags: deployment, parameters, jboss, weblogic

I have a WAR file already deployed in Weblogic by passing some Extra Java parameters. Now i require to deploy the same WAR in JBoss but not sure how to pass arguments to WAR

In Weblogic, while WAR deployment the arguments is passed like this as shown below

Open the DOMAIN_HOME/bin/setDomainEnv.cmd
In EXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES
set this property -Dcas.standalone.configurationDirectory=/some/path

In /some/path the cas.properties file will be placed which will be used by the WAR.

Now the requirement is i need to deploy this WAR in JBoss. How do i pass the cas.properties file for the WAR in JBoss during deployment.

Answer (score 0):

According to your WebLogic server deployment, you are setting custom system properties for that server which can be used by your application.

You can set system properties in JBoss using the following steps:

1. Login to JBoss admin console.
2. Click on the Runtime tab.
3. Select Server Groups and then select your server from the list.
4. Select and Click on View from the dropdown. The server configuration page will open.
5. On Server Configuration, click on System Properties.
6. Click on Add button to add new System properties for the server.

You can do it from backend as well by editing your `host.xml` file.

**Note:**

These System Properties are available throughout the configuration. The Boot-Time flag specifies if a property should be passed into the **JVM start (-Dproperty=value)**

Comment: The added System property is not available in host.xml or domain.xml.

Comment: Its is available in standalone.xml file. But the WAR is not picking up the properties file. Any Solutions?

Comment: Since the WAR was already deployed in Weblogic, it has weblogic.xml file inside it. It does not have standalone.xml file. Should the war file be added with the standalone.xml file. Im new to these deployments , please help

Comment: When i say it is not picking up the properties file, i mean to say deployment fails because unsatisfied dependency exception which caused because its not taking the value from the file

Comment: you are running standalone mode. so your system properties will appear in standalone.xml file of JBoss

Comment: @Vijaya can you share deployment error you getting, also share property which is getting added in standalone.xml file (share whole xml tag)